# (Beginner)RubyOnRails: MODELS

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, models

I have to learn how to create models in rails 4.1.0 (Ruby 2.0). I need create 2 models: Category and Post (one-to-many). Ok, my steps:

```
$ rails new test_work
$ cd test_work/
$ rails generate model Category \
> name:string
$ rails generate model Post \
> message:text
```

Then I changed my model files in such a way:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Then I run rake db:migrate and open rails console. After this I'm adding new Category:

```
category = Category.create name: "fghjk"
```

I want to be sure, that i haven't got posts yet:

```
2.0.0-p451 :002 > category.posts
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."category_id" = ?  [[nil, 1]]
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.category_id: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."category_id" = ?
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: posts.category_id: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE "posts"."category_id" = ?
```

What's the problem?

```
2.0.0-p451 :008 >   category.posts.create(message: "dsfsfdfs")
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute: category_id
```

Comment: Do you have `category_id` in `posts` table?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Rails. Nice you got so far, to figure out this problem take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn’t create a `category_id` field in the `posts` table to allow posts and categories to be related. Update the `posts` migration in `db/migrate/##_create_posts_table.rb` and add this:

```
t.references :category
```

Or, if you start over, you should generate the `Post` model like this:

```
rails generate model Post message:text category:references
```

You’ll have to undo your migrations with `rake db:rollback` and then run `rake db:migrate` again.

You could add another migration with the `category_id` field and then you wouldn’t need to roll back the migrations:

```
rails generate migration AddCategoryToPost category:references
```

Comment: But is it not enough that i added **belongs_to** and **has_many** to my models?

Comment: @McCauley No.. Your DB doesn't know about the relationship between 2 tables.. You have to let your DB know the fact. That's why migrations are there. Please do open your `schema.rb` file and see there, no such relationship is defined as per the current context.

Comment: No, that only tells Rails that it should use the `category_id` to find a related `Category`. The `category_id` field needs to exist in the database.

Comment: So i need add parent's table id only to Posts? How category finds posts then, if we didn't add post_id?

Comment: It wouldn’t make sense to add a `post_id` to a `Category` because it `has_many :posts`. In the `has_many` relation, Rails uses the “foreign key”, meaning the `id` field in the related table (`category_id` in this case), to find the other models.

Comment: Oh, thank's a lot, @BuckDoyle. Now everything is clear)